# Safe to utilize static compiled pattern within doGet() of servlet - matcher.replaceAll()

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, pattern-matching

Is it save to have:

```
    private static final String LUCENE_ESCAPE_CHARS = "[\\\\+\\-\\!\\(\\)\\:\\^\\]\\{\\}\\~\\*\\?]";
    private static final Pattern LUCENE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(LUCENE_ESCAPE_CHARS);
    private static final String REPLACEMENT_STRING = "\\\\$0";
```

And utilize the below in a multithreaded environment such as the `doGet()` of a servlet?

```
String escaped = LUCENE_PATTERN.matcher(query).replaceAll(REPLACEMENT_STRING);
```

My main concern is to now add additional delay (e.g. due to locks) or have a situation where bugs take place.

Comment: Most of the characters don't need escaping if they are inside a character class `[]`. Characters like `^` and `-` and `]` can be unescaped inside `[]` if you position them correctly. E.g.:

`final String LUCENE_ESCAPE_CHARS = "[]\\\\+!():^{}~*?-]";`

Comment: `]` doesn't need escaping if it follows the opening `[`. `^` doesn't need escaping if it isn't in the first position. `-` doesn't need escaping if it's in either first of last position.

Comment: @U Mad your referring to LUCENT specifically?

Comment: No I'm referring to java regular expressions. Generally most characters that otherwise need escaping don't need it inside character classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Yes*** it is safe.The `Pattern` object *is thread safe* and `Matcher` object *is not*. You can share the pattern instance with multiple threads.

But don't share the `Matcher` instance between threads.

Quoting JavaDoc for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> Instances of this class are *immutable* and are safe for use by multiple
>   concurrent threads. Instances of the `Matcher` class are *not safe* for
>   such use.